# Pandas Dataframe set Categories - The `inplace` parameter in pandas.Categorical.set_categories is deprecated

Tags: python, dataframe

I have following statement in my code:

```
mcap_summary['cap'].cat.set_categories(['Large','Mid','Small','None'],inplace=True)
```

Which now generates a warning as:
D:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\categorical.py:2630: FutureWarning: The `inplace` parameter in pandas.Categorical.set_categories is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Removing unused categories will always return a new Categorical object.
res = method(*args, **kwargs)

How am I suppose to write to avoid this warning and future errors?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pandas v1.3.0+ removed 'inplace' option.

so you can code like below:

```
mcap_summary['cap'] = mcap_summary['cap'].cat.set_categories(['Large', 'Mid', 'Small', 'None'])
```

Comment: thanks.
I had tried this earlier but the results were different.
This time tried again, and its working fine - then i realised the source data had changed :(

Thanks very much